# Uncaught referenceError: $counter is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, function, variables, referenceerror

I have a function in my JS file which i want to give a value by a PHP variable called $counter. I get an error: $counter is not defined.

Heres the PHP-Code:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

foreach($res as $category){                    
  echo '<div class="category" onmouseover="doChangeFontWeight($counter);" onmouseout="undoChangeFontWeight($counter);">';
  echo '<p class="categoryDescription">'.utf8_encode($category['description']).'</p>';
  echo '</div>';

  $counter++;
}
?>
```

Javascript:

```
function doChangeFontWeight(counter) {
"use strict";

document.getElementsByClassName("categoryDescription")[counter].setAttribute("style", "font-weight: 900");}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'<div class="category" onmouseover="doChangeFontWeight('.$counter.');" onmouseout="undoChangeFontWeight('.$counter.');">';
```

Variables aren't passed inside single quotes in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to echo using double quotes instead of single.

```
echo "<div class='category' onmouseover='doChangeFontWeight($counter);' onmouseout='undoChangeFontWeight($counter);'>";
echo "<p class='categoryDescription'>".utf8_encode($category['description'])."</p>";
echo "</div>";
```